# How to locate the username and password field within Instagram login page using Chromedriver and Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram, webdriverwait

Here's inspected source code

```
input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value=""
```

I have tried this code run

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]").send_keys(pw)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
```

But having error like this

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

My chromedriver and chrome version are match, and finding elements by following instruction. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

[Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/) application is built through [React](https://reactjs.org/) elements. Hence just after invoking the url when you initiate the search for the login element, you face [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

---

### Solution

To login within *Instagram* using a valid set of credentials you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("username")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("password")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/div[text()='Log In']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: instagram_login]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Filling in login forms in Instagram using selenium and webdriver (chrome) python OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938766/filling-in-login-forms-in-instagram-using-selenium-and-webdriver-chrome-python/49939562#49939562)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)

Comment: thank you for solution.. but now I having an issue that as soon as logging in, quit from webbrowser...

Comment: @JohnnyJeong Seems like a different issue. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?

Comment: Thank you! After trying a lot of things, this worked for me with a slight change. I had to add a timer after sending the password. I also had to accept the cookies as soon as the window opened in Chrome.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Thanks for the link. I can vote your answer if you add the timer and the cookies' acceptance to it. Your answer didn't work without these two details, thus my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that while open instagram homepage, it shows spinner on login form for few moment and then display the fields. So your need to manage synchronization in your script.

Use explicit wait in your code until desired field get ready for interaction.

```
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")))
username.send_keys('username')
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
password.send_keys('pw')
```

Need to import below packages

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
txt_user = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'username')))
txt_user.send_keys('yourUserName')
txt_pwd = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password')))
txt_pwd.send_keys('yourPassword')
btn_submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[type="submit"]')))
btn_submit.click()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "//input[@name=\"username\"]"))
)
element.sendkeys('user')
```